# Save view to image - location or not working

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image, android-file, save-image

I'm trying to save my view as an image. I have done some work, doesn't show any error but I can find the location where is the image saved(or in the gallery). Is the image created at all, or I'm having some other issues? The image should be saved when pressing red from options menu:

```
case R.id.red:
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                String FILENAME="Boenka";
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                parent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                parent.draw(canvas); 
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); 
                return true;
```

This is my main - Draw class

```
public class Draw extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    SignatureView signature;
    private RelativeLayout parent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.signImageParent);
        signature = new SignatureView(getApplicationContext(), null);
        signature.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        parent.addView(signature);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.clear:
            signature.clear();
            return true;

        case R.id.red:
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String FILENAME="Boenka";
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            parent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            parent.draw(canvas); 
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); 
            return true;

        case R.id.blue:
            signature.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            return true;
        case R.id.yellow:
            signature.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap b,int count) throws Exception
    {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;

        String s=at.getText().toString();
        String alphaAndDigits = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","_");


        String fileName = alphaAndDigits+"_"+wr.name+"_"+count;
        File file = new File(path, fileName+".jpg");
        newFile=Uri.fromFile(file);
        uris.add(newFile);
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
    }
```

Try this function it worked well for me, this is for saving the bitmap please ensure that drawing cache is working fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code, it works**

**Add below permission in manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private DrawableView drawableView;   //here I have taken customview, it is optional, I am saving this view as image. You can take any layout or view
private Button saveBtn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    drawableView = (DrawableView) findViewById(R.id.drawable_view);
    saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.save_btn:
        File file = saveBitMap(this, drawableView);    //which view you want to pass that view as parameter
        if (file != null) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Drawing saved to the gallery!");
        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "Oops! Image could not be saved.");
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

private File saveBitMap(Context context, View drawView){
    File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Handcare");
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
        if(!isDirectoryCreated)
            Log.i("ATG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
        return null;
    }
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() +File.separator+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.");
    }       
        scanGallery(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), context);
    return pictureFile;
}
//create bitmap from view and returns it
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }   else{
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
// used for scanning gallery
private void scanGallery(Context cntx, String path) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(cntx, new String[] { path },null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}